# Dump a Table from MySQL Database directly from sql server using bash

Tags: linux, mysql, bash

How can I dump a table from a MySQL database using a bash script?

Like we can use the below command to dump a table

```
mysql -u username -p database_name > file.sql
```

But how can I dump only a single table from a database?

Can someone please help me for the same?

Comment: The command you gave does not dump any data. You should check to make sure you paste in the exact commands you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME MYTABLE > DBNAME-MYTABLE.sql
```

For backup purposes you might want to add a date like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cur=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME MYTABLE > DBNAME-MYTABLE-${cur}.sql
```